# Modificar campo de tabla al hacer click en el campo booleano

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo una consulta select para que me muestre los examenes que ha hecho un alumno en una tabla. Hay dos campos de esa tabla que los modifico dinámicamente con select en javascript pero tengo otro campo booleano que me gustaría que al hacerle click cambiase de 0 (no ha hecho el examen) a 1 (ha hecho el examen). El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<td><div class="select1" id="type-<?php echo $id_appl ?>"><?php echo $row['type']?></div></td>

<td> <?php echo $examen ?>
// este es el campo que me gustaria cambiar al hacer click de 0 a 1 o viceversa//                                                                                                                          </td>

$(document).ready(function() { 

// ambos procesaran en save.php 

// servira para editar los de tipo input text. 
$('.text').editable('colleges_save.php'); 

// servira para editar el cuadro combinado de paises 
$('.select1').editable('colleges_save.php', { 
data : " {'EAC':'EAC','ED1':'ED1','ED2':'ED2', 'REG':'REG', 'ROL':'ROL'}", 
type : 'select', 
submit : 'Ok' 
});

$('.select2').editable('colleges_save.php', { 
data : " {'Pending':'Pending','Accepted':'Accepted','Denied':'Denied', 'Waitlist':'Waitlist'}", 
type : 'select', 
submit : 'Ok' 
}); 

// servira para editar el textarea. 
$('.textarea').editable('colleges_save.php', { 
type : 'textarea', 
submit : 'Ok' 
}); 

});
```

COLLEGES_SAVE.PHP

```
$data = explode("-",$_POST['id']); 
$campo = $data[0]; // nombre del campo
$id = $data[1]; // id del registro 
$value = $_POST['value']; // valor por el cual reemplazar 


// sql para actualizar el registro 
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE applications SET ".$campo." = '".$value."' 
WHERE id_application = '".$id."'" ); 
echo ($campo == 'id_pais') ? $paises[$value] : $value; 
?>
```

Comment: Cuando te refieres a cambiar, quieres decir actualizar el registros en la base de datos?

Comment: Exacto, perdón por el término.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En general deberias de asignarle un evento el elemento que deseas que actualize el registro en la base de datos. Una vez se le dio clic al evento, envias la peticion ajax a la pagina `COLLEGES_SAVE.PHP` con sus repectivos parametros:

```
$("#registro-db").click(function(){
   var id = obtenerId();
   var data ={ 
     id : id,
     //aqui definirias los demas campos
   };

   $.post("/COLLEGES_SAVE.PHP", data, function(response){
          alert("estado actualizado");
   });

});
```

Comment: es lo que buscaba... gracias... no habia caido en asignarle evento...